# Google Speech API iOS streaming example, no response?

Tags: ios, google-api, speech-to-text

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Streaming

I can see my requests in my https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/usage?project=pokerspeechhack&duration=P1D but I have no responses.

I added logging to the sample project to see that when I click the stop streaming button that it goes into the no response flow.

Anybody else run into this when setting up/running the demo?

Comment: Did you manage to sort it out ?

Comment: Did you enable Google Cloud Speech API for your application and enabled billing?

Comment: Not enough information about your problem.